# Sort list that includes float numbers and words with number

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to sort a list with the following values

My list

```
list_to_sort = ['1.1.0','1.2.3','1.3.10','1.3.9','x23','hi']
```

My expected output

```
['1.1.0','1.2.3','1.3.9','1.3.10','hi','x23']
```

What i have tried:

```
list_to_sort .sort()
```

I have never done something like this so I would love to know how I could solve it. Thanks!

Comment: those arent floats

Comment: What did you try? Where did it fail? Please share what you tried.

Comment: This involves multiple steps and possible techniques. It is unclear which parts of this you already know and which you don't.

Comment: I know that they are strings. Note that 1.3.10 is bigger than 1.3.9. That's why I am not using list_to_sort.sort() which is wrong on this case.

Comment: are `hi` and `x23` outliers?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Since you haven't specified your sort rationale, and haven't shown your attempted code, this is not yet a good question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This was, needless to say, an interesting one to solve

```
list_to_sort = ['1.1.0', '1.2.0','4.3.0' ,'1.3.10','1.3.9','1.31.0','x23','hi']

def weirdFloats(x):
    try:
        #trips an error when given something like "hi"
        return [int(i) for i in x.split(".")]
    except:
        return [float("Inf"), x]

print(sorted(list_to_sort, key= weirdFloats, reverse= False))
```

```
['1.1.0', '1.2.0', '1.3.9', '1.3.10', '1.31.0', '4.3.0', 'hi', 'x23']
```

> Note that im not sure if this properly accounts for things that cant be interpreted as what you call "floats" (they look more like version #'s to me) such as what seem to be the outliers here `hi` and `x23`

Comment: should be fixed.

Comment: OK, I misread it

Comment: Thats alright, hopefully this helps op, idk what he wants to do with those other values

Comment: This helped me! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're very welcome! If you found this answer or one that comes in the future useful you can click the green checkmark under its score to accept it for people with the same question! Thanks for asking and happy coding :)